# C++ getline inside while loop missing first letter. Does not work without cin.ignore?

Tags: c++, while-loop, cin, getline

I have been playing with for over a week with no success. The way it runs now, it will skip the first letter of the first iteration of my while loop. If I remove `cin.ignore()`, below code does not work.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main(){
    cout << fixed << setprecision(2);
    float gpaTot = 0, gpa, clasNum;
    int creds;
    string clas, cont = "Yes", grade;

    while (cont == "Yes"){
        cin.ignore();
        cout <<"Enter a course name: ";
        getline(cin, clas);
        cout << clas << endl << "Enter number of credits: ";
        cin >> creds;
        cout << creds << endl << "Enter your grade (A, B, C, D, F): ";
        cin >> grade;
        cout << grade << endl << "Continue ('Yes' or 'No')? ";
        cin >> cont;
        cout << cont << endl;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Move the `cin.ignore()` call to the end of the loop.

```
while (cont == "Yes"){
    cout <<"Enter a course name: ";
    getline(cin, clas);
    cout << clas << endl << "Enter number of credits: ";
    cin >> creds;
    cout << creds << endl << "Enter your grade (A, B, C, D, F): ";
    cin >> grade;
    cout << grade << endl << "Continue ('Yes' or 'No')? ";
    cin >> cont;
    cout << cont << endl;
    cin.ignore();
}
```

With that, the first call to `getline` does not skip a letter. The subsequent calls also work ok because the newline character from left over from the `cin >> cont;` line gets read and discarded by `cin.ignore()`.